# How to organize models for web application using firebase cloud functions

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am creating a Angular Application with firebase and typescript firebase cloud functions.

When it comes to saving models, i have a separate model folders in my cloud functions and in my angular application.
So when I have to change my models, I have to adapt every change two times which is very annoying.

Is there any better way to organize my models?

Comment: This kinda depends on your folder structure. Using something like Mx Monorepo would solve this as you’ll have both your Angular app(s) and cloudfunctions inside the same root with shared libs that can contain your shared models.

Comment: Please read "[How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)", "[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" and their linked pages.  Additionally, there's a Firebase documentation that you can check to [organize multiple functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/organize-functions), however, you should know that you can use the `require()` function to pull in code from other files into your index.js.